# Nested class definitions

Tags: c++, inner-classes

Just had a quick question about defining functions with nested classes.

Given the example below:

```
class OuterClass   {
     class InnerClass{
         public:
         void someMethod();
     };

     InnerClass someFunction();

};
```

I understand for the definition of someMethod in a .cpp you could do:

```
 void OuterClass::InnerClass::someMethod() { 
    // stuff}
```

But how would the definition for InnerClass someFunction go?

Comment: `InnerClass OuterClass::SomeFunction() { ...}`

Comment: Technically, it is a "method" (aka member function) too, so calling one `someMethod()` and the other `someFunction()` is misleading,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
OuterClass::InnerClass OuterClass::someFunction()
{
    // Code here...
}
```

---

The same rules apply to both `InnerClass` and `someFunction` : they are declared inside `OuterClass`, so they must be qualified with `OuterClass::` to be reached.